# Implementing Navigation Drawer in Activity with Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am currently redesigning my app to include a navigation drawer for navigating through the app. Currently, each screen is an activity and the way I have designed the home screen, is that it contains a toolbar and another xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_95sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sync_green"
        android:id="@+id/sync_button"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_75sdp"/>
</Toolbar>
<include layout="@layout/activity_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/run"
   />
```

Now, I have made another XML file for the navigation drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

My dilemna is that since my toolbar is in the home.xml fragment, when I switch fragments, I will lose the toolbar. I want to keep the toolbar for all the views in the navigation drawer.

Also, in my java code, the setActionBar(toolbar) is throwing up an error saying cannot resolve method setActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

One simple and straightforwrd solution for integrating NavigationDrawer along with Fragment in an Activity, is to design the `activity_main.xml` the following way :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_act_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/flat_white_light">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now, in the `content_act_main.xml` you can have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you notice, in the `conten_act_main.xml`, there is a toolbar that will be available to all the content that are shown in the `FrameLayout`, and you can use this FrameLayout as the container of your Fragments.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: This works, except now my layout is horribly ruined. Any suggestions? http://tinypic.com/r/2rwkinc/9

Comment: Show the xml of the layout in the picture

Comment: This layout is in a file called main.xml which is part of home.xml which is part of content.xml. If you have an email, I can post it to you. Its too much to show here.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course maintain this toolbar, you need *`ActionBarDrawerToggle`* to bind the *`drawerLayout`* and *`Toolbar`* together.

Minimal configuration would be more or less :

```
 ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }
```

And you put the Toolbar in your base activity layout and other views wrapped in *`DrawerLayout`*.

```
  <Android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:Android="http://schemas.Android.com/apk/res/Android"
        Android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        Android:layout_width="match_parent"
        Android:layout_height="match_parent"
        Android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:Android="http://schemas.Android.com/apk/res/Android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.Android.com/apk/res-auto"
            Android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            Android:layout_width="match_parent"
            Android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        ....
        ....
    </Android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Not able to. setSupportActionbar is not resolved. And if I don't use the support library, then the ActionBarDrawerToggle() function doesn't take in the correct parameters.

Comment: Ya. In most cases *setSupportActionbar* being recognized under `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and extending `AppCompatActivity`or `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Not able to. setSupportActionbar is not resolved. And if I don't use the support library, then the ActionBarDrawerToggle() function doesn't take in the correct parameters. I passed the constructor without the "toolbar" parameter and my screen is all skewed up now. http://tinypic.com/r/2nki6pd/9

Comment: Richeek, try with these combinations and see if it works *Android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;*, *Android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;*, and *Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;* and base activity extending *ActionBarActivity* . The toolbar is somehow overlayed with the drawer since being not correctly passed in the ActionBarDrawerToggle()

Comment: Have a look at [*this*](http://techlovejump.com/navigation-drawer-toolbar-android-using-material-design/), may it helps you. And if the fragments themselves corresponding with  items for the drawerlayout then check [*this*](http://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial) out

Answer (score 0):

**Try This in your activity**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This is my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/apptoolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nav_toolbar"
            android:clickable="true">

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/appColor"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:itemBackground="@color/appColor"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawable_selector_drawer_item"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: So I should put my toolbar in the base activity? What about the XML? Can I put it along with the drawerlayout? And I can't use supportActionBar, I'm not using the support library for this toolbar.